# replace number in column with corresponding string using MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

SQL query to get |A|test1,test3| from this both table A1,A2
A1

```
| permission | user |
| ---------- | -----|
| 7,9        |  A   |
| 10,7       |  B   |
```

A2

```
| permission | fullname |
| ---------- | ---------|
| 7          |  test1   |
| 10         |  test2   |
| 9          |  test3   |
```

I need a query that gives me **user, fullname**
example

```
|A|test1,test3|
 |B|test2,test1|
```

replace number with there corresponding string

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Properly declare foreign key constraints!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_in_set()`

```
SELECT user,group_concat(fullname) as fullname
FROM
  t1 LEFT JOIN t2
  ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.permission,t1.permission)
  group by user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like as follows:

```
Select user,group_concat(fullname) as fullname
  From A1 join A2 on concat(',',A2.permission,',') 
                     like concat(concat('%,',A1.permission,',%')
Group by user;
```